# Proving Cauchy criterion for functions without choice.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Given any $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $f : D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ , let $a$ be a limit point of $D$.
Then $f$ $\space$has a limit at $a$  if and only if : 
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \space  \exists \delta>0 \space \forall x,y \in D \space (0 < |x-a|<\delta \space\land \space0 < |y-a|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon)$$
I found this theorem [Here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Analysis_I_(Lafferriere_Lafferriere_and_Nguyen)/03%3A_Limits_and_Continuity/3.02%3A_Limit_Theorems) labeled "Theorem 3.2.2: Cauchy's criterion". 
But for proving the backwards implication, the proof in that website starts by fixing some sequence ${\{u_n\}}$ without explicitly mentioning a construction. So I thought they used countable choice. So here is my question:

> Is there a way to prove Cauchy criterion for functions without choice?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] My original post pointed out that the Cauchy Criterion for functions is equivalent to the Supremum property, and that they imply the Cauchy Criterion for sequences without invoking choice, but opined that proving the Cauchy Criterion for sequences implied the other two might require countable choice. This was because I was thinking the Cauchy sequence had to be built inside an arbitrary set, which Shinrin-Yoku's comment made me realize was not true. Any sequence converging to the needed limit is sufficient.

---

I tried to come up with a direct proof that the C.C. (Cauchy Criterion) for sequences proved (without choice) the C.C. for functions, but kept running into technical details that made it sloppy. I think a proof by the Supremum property will be cleaner.

So given that Cauchy sequences converge, we want to prove first that a bounded non-empty set of real numbers has a supremum. Let $A$ be such a set. Then we can choose an element $x_0 \in A$, and an upper bound $z_0$ for $A$. Define $y_0 = \frac {x_0+z_0}2$. Continue recursively:

- If $y_n$ is an upper bound for $A$, then define $x_{n+1} = x_n, z_{n+1} = y_n$. Otherwise, define $x_{n+1} = y_n, z_{n+1} = z_n$. In either case, $y_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n+1}+z_{n+1}}2$.

Then always $x_n \le x_{n+1} < z_{n+1} \le z_n$ and $z_n - x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore $\{x_n\}_n, \{z_n\}_n$ are Cauchy sequences, and must converge to the same limit $L$. Since the $z_n$ are all upper bounds, their limit $L$ is also an upper bound. But the none of the $x_n$ are upper bounds, which means there have to be elements of $A$ between $x_n$ and $L$ (possibly just $L$ itself). As the $x_n \to L$, every neighborhood of $L$ must contain elements of $A$. Thus $L$ is the supremum of $A$. Note that only the two points $x_0, z_0$ were arbitrary choices, so the axiom of choice was not used.

To show that the Supremum property implies the C.C. for functions, note that the existence of the supremum and infimum for bounded sets means that $$\limsup_{x\to a} f(x)\\\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)$$ are always well-defined (in general by allowing $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ to be values, but if $f$ is Cauchy at $a$, then it must be bounded in a neighborhood of $a$ and the liminf and limsup must be finite). If $\liminf_{x\to a}f(x) < \limsup_{x\to a} f(x)$ then by choosing an $\epsilon$ smaller than the difference, we see that $f$ would not meet the Cauchy condition. Thus it must be that $$\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)=\limsup_{x\to a} f(x)$$ and therefore the full limit must exist and converge to the common value.

Comment: To prove that Dedekind and Cauchy reals are equivalent no choice is required, so your proof seems to go through irrespective of the definition of the reals.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku - thanks. You make me think about it, and I realized that given a bounded set, you can create a Cauchy sequence converging to its upper bound by choosing a point $a$ in the set and an upper bound $b$, and effectively do a bisection search for the supremum. The lower bounds of the intervals forms the desired sequence, and only the two initial points were arbitrary, so indeed, no choice is required. I'll update my post later when I have more time.